# How to send object to server in java

Tags: java

I create my class in a client and use a server for communication between client and server, but I have a problem to convert this class. I send an object of my class from the client to the server, but the server notices this object is not from the same class.

My class implements Serializable and I use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream to send and receive this object.

How can I let the server know that this object is from the same class as in the client?

```
//Client site.
toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(myClient.getOutputStream());
fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(myClient.getInputStream());
toServer.writeObject(new MyClass("12345",12345));


//Server site.
fromClient = new ObjectInputStream(connectFromClient.getInputStream());
toClient = new ObjectOutputStream(connectFromClient.getOutputStream());
MyClass message = (MyClass) fromClient.readObject();
```

Comment: Could you please post your code for sending, receving and "convert"ing your object ? Did you try to cast ?

Comment: Are you certain you have the same classes available in both ends?  Also check the serial numbers.

Comment: I post my code in questions now. Please see my questions.

Comment: This is a homework/ study question, right? Because otherwise you could use a framework such as EJBs (which wouldn't solve your current problem, but simplifies a lot of the server code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a third project, which has the classes used by both the client and the server and create a jar. Then add that jar to the classpath of the server and the client application.

Answer (score 3):

The classes which you serialize have to be in the same packages on the client and the server side. For example if you have serialized class Demo in package demo.bin in the client project you have to make the same serialized class in the same package in the server project.
If you create the server and the client in one project please post some code to see where is the problem.

Comment: No, they are in different packages.

Comment: To correct the error move the classes in the same packages and the problem will be fix.